# Mapping for context suggester failed in ElasticSearch 2

Tags: elasticsearch

After updating to ElasticSearch 2 I am no more able to map the [ContextSuggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html) for different types:

```
PUT /test/foo/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "suggest": {
      "type": "completion",
      "context": {
        "type": {
          "type": "category",
          "path": "_type",
          "default": [
            "foo"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /test/bar/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "suggest": {
      "type": "completion",
      "context": {
        "type": {
          "type": "category",
          "path": "_type",
          "default": [
            "bar"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Putting the map for the second type ends in the following exception:

> Mapper for [suggest] conflicts with existing mapping in other types: [mapper [suggest] has different [context_mapping] values]

The problem is that the default value differs for the different types. From my point of view, this should be the expected approach. How can I solve this problem?

*Tested version of ES: 2.2.1*

Answer (score 1):

You have a field conflict.

[Mapping - field conflicts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#field-conflicts)

> Mapping types are used to group fields, **but the fields in each
>   mapping  type are not independent of each other**. Fields with:
>
> - the same name
> - in the same index
> - in different mapping types
>
> map to the same field internally, and must have the same mapping. If a
>   `title` field exists in both the `user` and `blogpost` mapping types, the
>   `title` fields must have exactly the same mapping in each type. The only
>   exceptions to this rule are the `copy_to`, `dynamic`, `enabled`,
>   `ignore_above`, `include_in_all`, and `properties` parameters, which may
>   have different settings per field.

Either create a separate index or rename the field for the other type.